# Zend Framework 2: creating web forms using plain html in the view

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, frameworks, zend-framework2

At present, I use this:

```
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>
        <?php echo $this->formHidden($form->get('page_id')); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('title')); ?>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('content')); ?>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('url_slug')); ?>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit')); ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

to display my form in the view script, but I would like to add some additional styling, html attributes, etc so it would be better to write the form in plain html. So far so good, but is it possible to display the form errors in the html view without using the methods above? In ZF1, I used:

```
 <ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->form->class->getMessages() as $key => $value): ?>
        <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach ($this->form->letter->getMessages() as $key => $value): ?>
        <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach ($this->form->type->getMessages() as $key => $value): ?>
        <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
//the html of the form
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formElementErrors view helper to get the error messages for each element as follows:

```
<ul>

    <li>
         <?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get($form->get('title')) ?>
         <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get($form->get('title'))) ?>
         <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get($form->get('title')), array('class' => 'errors')) ?>
    </li>
    <li>
         <?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get($form->get('content')) ?>
         <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get($form->get('content'))) ?>
         <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get($form->get('content')), array('class' => 'errors')) ?>
    </li>

</ul>
```

You can also have more control over your HTML like this:

```
<li>
   <?php echo $form->get('content')->getLabel() ?>
    <input class="some-class" type="text" 
       name="<?php echo $form->get('content')->getName() ?>"
       value="<?php echo $form->get('content')->getValue() ?>"
    />
</li>
```

If you want to get all form errors:

```
<?php foreach($form->getMessages() as $errors): ?>
    <?php var_dump($errors) // Array for messages for each input ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I discovered a day ago and it works perfectly. Thanks, indeed. :)